# Navigationbar hidden while runtime? iOS 8.1 - xCode 6.0

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationcontroller

the navigationbar is shown in the storyboard but hidden while runtime... (see screens):

any hints?

[image: fromiPhone]
[image: fromStoryboard]

Answer (score 0):

First，please go to your UINavigationController in storyboard and make 'Shows Navigation Bar' selected. Just like this:
[storyboard setting sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRWHX.png)

If method above makes no sense, you can write code in your UIViewController to make navigation bar visible by force:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
}
```